# Install KarmaSphere plugin in NetBeans

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, netbeans-plugins, word-count

I want to run a Hadoop MapReduce program (for example WordCount) with NetBeans. I found that there is "KarmaSphere studio for Hadoop" that is a plugin in NetBeans.

I followed the instructions given in the link below, to install the plugin : http://www.hadoopstudio.org/home/installation-guide/

But, when I add the plugin name and URL, the "KarmaSphere Studio" does not appear in my available plugins. So I can not download and install it.

I have NetBeans 7.3.1 with JDK7.

Anybody knows what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

It seems netbeans is not supported by karmasphere studio for hadoop.For programming Hadoop in Eclipse, see here http://arifn.web.id/blog/2012/05/15/programming-hadoop-in-eclipse.html